# How to declare and initialize a 4x3 2D array of doubles called scores. Use initializer lists to store the first exam scores in the first column

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, double

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
public class Review {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        //First, declare and initialize a 4x3 2D array of doubles called `scores` which will contain the exam data for four students. The rows will represent the student and the columns will represent the exam number. You already know the first exam scores (80.4, 96.2, 100.0, 78.9). Use initializer lists to store the first exam scores in the first column and -1 for the remaining exams. Use the provided print statement to print the result in the console.
  double[][] scores = new double[4][];
  scores[0] = new double[] {80.4, 96.2, 100.0, 78.9};
  scores[1] = new double[] {-1};
  scores[2] = new double[] {-1};
  scores[3] = new double[] {-1};



  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(scores));

    //The next set of exams have occurred. Using 4 lines of code, manually enter the scores (89.7, 90.5, 93.6, 88.1) for the second exam (column 1). Use the provided print statement to print the updated 2D array as well.


  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(scores));
        
  //You have realized that you will only be keeping track of 2 exam grades instead of 3. Declare and initialize an empty 4x2 2D array of double values  called newScores
  double[][] newScores = null;


  //Using loops, copy all of the scores for exam 1 and 2 into the new 2D array. (do not include the -1 values)


  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newScores));

  //You have allowed the students to complete an extra credit activity to contribute towards their scores. For all exam grades less than 90, add 2 additional points to the grade in `newScores`


  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newScores));
    }
}
```

Below is the question I have and below is what I have tried.
This part "**First, declare and initialize a 4x3 2D array of doubles called `scores` which will contain the exam data for four students. The rows will represent the student and the columns will represent the exam number**". throws me off. I don't get it.

```
    //First, declare and initialize a 4x3 2D array of doubles called `scores` which will contain the exam data for four students. The rows will represent the student and the columns will represent the exam number. You already know the first exam scores (80.4, 96.2, 100.0, 78.9). Use initializer lists to store the first exam scores in the first column and -1 for the remaining exams. Use the provided print statement to print the result in the console.


  double[][] scores = new double[4][];
  scores[0] = new double[] {80.4, 96.2, 100.0, 78.9};
  scores[1] = new double[] {-1};
  scores[2] = new double[] {-1};
  scores[3] = new double[] {-1};



  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(scores));
```

Here's the output from the console.

```
    [[80.4, 96.2, 100.0, 78.9], [-1.0], [-1.0], [-1.0]]
    [[80.4, 96.2, 100.0, 78.9], [-1.0], [-1.0], [-1.0]]
    null
    null
```

Here's the hint of the question. "Remember to use nested initializer lists like so: `datatype[][] variable = {{val1, val2, val3}, {val4, val5, val6}, {val7, val8, val9}};`.

Comment: What exactly don't you get? I'd suggest using the hint, although the way you are initialising the array will work too.

Comment: @tgdavies I did use the hint format but still not working. double[][] scores = {{80.4, 96.2, 100.0, 78.9}, {-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1}}; but not working.

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks for your help. Here's the correct format. double[][] scores = {{80.4, -1, -1}, {96.2, -1, -1}, {100.0, -1, -1}, {78.9, -1, -1}};

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this;

```
    double[][] scores = new double[][]{{80.4, 96.2, 100.0, 78.9}, {-1, -1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1}};
```

or like this;

```
    double[][] scores = new double[4][3];
    Arrays.stream(scores).forEach(x -> Arrays.fill(x, -1));
    scores[0] = new double[]{80.4, 96.2, 100.0, 78.9};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here's the correct format. double[][] scores = {{80.4, -1, -1}, {96.2, -1, -1}, {100.0, -1, -1}, {78.9, -1, -1}};

Answer (score 0):

4x3 2D array means 4 rows and 3 columns i.e. 4 students and 3 exams.
In my snippets, I have created 3x4 2D array with 3 rows (students) and 4 columns(exams)

The 4 students have taken their first exam and have been graded. They still have to take the remaining two exams.

Here's the correct format.

```
double[][] scores = {{80.4, -1, -1}, {96.2, -1, -1}, {100.0, -1, -1}, {78.9, -1, -1}};
```